# get photos from old iphone to new iphone through icloud data backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I just bought a new iPhone 6 and I want all my old photos in the camera roll to my new phone.

I was using an iPhone 5 and I keep all my photos backed up on my iCloud account.

If possible, how do I get all those photos in my new phone through iCloud?

Comment: Set up your new iPhone using your iCloud backup.

Answer (score 1):

Check Use iCloud backup part.
Check this out :  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201269